# Different result when using mix-blend-mode and background-blend-mode

Tags: css, background-blend-mode, mix-blend-mode

I've noticed that when using `mix-blend-mode` the result is different than when using `background-blend-mode` even though you're using the same blending mode.

For example, compare the 2 results below:

[image: Image with background-blend-mode] [image: Image with mix-blend-mode]

I've copied in my setup and JSFiddles below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  //background-color:green; //toggle depending on what you want to use
  background-blend-mode:soft-light;
  background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-640-480-2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}

.overlay{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:green; //toggle depending on what you want to use
  mix-blend-mode:soft-light;
}
```

**JSFiddle**

Using mix-blend-mode: https://jsfiddle.net/p8gkna87/

Using background-blend-mode: https://jsfiddle.net/p8gkna87/1/

**Some background information**

I'm currently replicating a photoshop design which uses the soft-light blending mode and at the same time also uses an opacity of 51%. So it wouldn't be able to use `background-blend-mode` as the opacity cannot be applied to the same object.

Comment: Yes, you can apply opacity on the same object... Or you don't mean opacity against backdrop ?

Comment: @vals The idea is that the color is 51% opacity on softlight while the background remains at 100% opacity. I don't believe using the same layer would be possible in that case. However, I just realised this might work with rgba - just tried this and that seems to work. However, the original question still remains - why is there a difference between the 2 blend modes.

Comment: Yes, you can use `rgba` to make background color semi-transparent  without affecting the background image

Comment: A minor note, using `//` when making comments in CSS is invalid and might give you unpredictable result, use `/* */` instead

Comment: @LGSon Good point, I'm using sass though :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`background-blend-mode` blends with its `background-image` and its `background-color`.

`mix-blend-mode` blends with its *backdrop*, the part what is behind itself, *and* its `background-color`.

Here is an article describing `mix-blend-mode` quite well:

- http://alistapart.com/article/blending-modes-demystified

Put in another way, and in your case, with your `mix-blend-mode` you blend a green color on top of the image, with your `background-blend-mode` you do the opposite.

So by having the same layer order, both `blend-modes` look the same

```css
.background,
.background2{
  display: inline-block;
}

.background{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
}
.overlay{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  mix-blend-mode:soft-light;
  background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-640-480-2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}

.background2{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  background-blend-mode:soft-light;
  background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-640-480-2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="background2">
</div>
```

Comment: I might be missing something but I don't believe any of the images are blending now? They just display the original image

Comment: @user2019515 That is correct. Removed the sample as they don't prove anything.

Comment: It seems that the "green" colour is used in both the left and right result images though, so it seems that mix-blend-mode is using the green as well, however, likely in a different way (which I'm trying to get to the bottom off)

Comment: @user2019515 Made a final update ... I missed one thing how I described it for `mix-blend-mode`

Comment: @user2019515 Updated again + added a sample

Answer (score 5):

You have already a good answer from LGSon.

Just to clarify it a little bit further:

The layers that you have here are, from botton to top:

1. background element background-color
2. background element image
3. overlay element background-color

The background-blendmode applies **inside** the background element, in this case layer 2 over layer 1

The mix-blend-mode applies element 3 over the result of 1 + 2

So, if only one of them is efffective, the order is the inverse

Comment: Thanks ... +1 ... this looks more _academic_ :)

Comment: Even though the explanation is pretty much the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like to me that `mix-blend-mode` also uses `background-color` to blend it when `background-blend-mode` doesn't.
test using and change `background-color` as well:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-blend-mode